# Resource on Load, extract data and send data via Azure Data Facory V2 to Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am seeking resources on how to implement this scenario below.

I found some documentation, but I cannot find steps 2 and 3 below

Using Azure Data Facory V2 to

1. Load a *.csv file from SFP server

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp
2. extract rows from the *.csv file based on condition in column

   There might be three separate extracted data, thus three sepearte Azure Aunction App.
3. send each extracted data to each Azure Function App

Answer (score 0):

One way to structure a pipeline for this is:

1. Lookup Activity
2. Filter Activity
3. Azure Function Activity

(connected by success dependencies)

For each of your three cases, you can branch out from the single Lookup activity to three Filter Activities, each leading into their own Azure Function activity.

The details of each activity depend upon your situation, but here are some examples.

In the Filter activity,Items can look like `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`
Condition can look like `@greater(int(item()['My Number']),0)`.